# Ocaml - Files and parsing

Tags: file, parsing, ocaml, string-parsing, file-read

How to read contents from file in ocaml? Specifically how to parse them?

Example :

Suppose file contains `(a,b,c);(b,c,d)| (a,b,c,d);(b,c,d,e)|`

then after reading this, I want two lists containing `l1 = [(a,b,c);(b,c,d)]` and `l2 = [(a,b,c,d);(b,c,d,e)]`

Is there any good tutorial for parsing?

Comment: Please do not repost questions. If you have anything new to add to your existing question, please edit it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify a grammar and have ocaml generate lexers and parsers for you, check out these [ocamllex](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamllex-tutorial/) and [ocamlyacc](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamlyacc-tutorial/) tutorials.  I recommend doing it this way.  If you really only have one type of token in your file format, then ocamlyacc might be overkill if you can just use the lexer to split the file up into tokens that are considered valid by the grammar.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good use case for the [menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) parser generator (successor to `ocamlyacc`). You might want to use `ocamllex` for lexing. All have good documentation.

You could also use *camlp4* or *camlp5* stream parsing abilities.

Read also the wikipedia pages on [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing) & [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to use [Aurochs](https://github.com/berke/aurochs), a PEG parser for something like this.  There is example code in the repo there.